# convert pid_t to const char* with stringstream

Tags: c++, string, pid, stringstream

I want to convert a process pid to a const char* but below does not work:

```
            std::ostringstream str_pid;
        str_pid << getpid();
        const char * cstr_pid = str_pid.str().c_str();
```

It works most of the time but sometimes it has a false result. Apparently i am doing something wrong.
Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cstr_pid` will be a dangling pointer, as the temporary `std::string` returned by `str_pid.str()` is destructed after the assignment of `cstr_pid`. Create a copy of the `str_pid.str()` return value:

```
const std::string my_pid(str_pid.str());
```

then use `my_pid.c_str()` when `const char*` is required.

Comment: But, it can occurs the same with my_pid if it is destructed after construction with str_pid.str(). He is dealing with life time objects, if he is returning my_pid.c_str(), he will have problems.

Comment: @coelhudo, I do not recommend caching the return value of `c_str()` in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I know, anyway, I was wondering if somehow this was inside a function and returning the internal reference.

Comment: I just chose to use the temporary object within the scope of an expression only: like: mq_send(queue_fd, str_pid.str().c_str(), str_pid.str().length(), 0 ). I guess there is no danger in such constructs.